# deleting products from database and reloading into stock

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When you add a product to the cart, the number of products in stock decreases and when you remove the product from the cart, it returns to the old stock number.

What I want to do the deletion automatically every half hour. This code only works for one product. When I add the second product to the cart, only the first product's stock is returned. Can you help me?

I tried mongoose expire but it just cleans the database and the stocks don't come back.

And when I add the second product I get this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: VersionError: No matching document found for id "60b21e0f0bfc782b80b17e8f" version 31 modifiedPaths "cart, cart.items"
```

And this is console output:

```js
[
  {
    _id: 60b3487145fab827845f87b1,
    productId: 60b24b9e89389908c8bbb3b2,
    quantity: 1
  }
]
user.product:  60b24b9e89389908c8bbb3b2 productId:  60b24b9e89389908c8bbb3b2
[
  {
    _id: 60b3487145fab827845f87b1,
    productId: 60b24b9e89389908c8bbb3b2,
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    _id: 60b3487a45fab827845f87b2,
    productId: 60b25119c9f0da205409d6ce,
    quantity: 1
  }
]
user.product:  60b24b9e89389908c8bbb3b2 productId:60b25119c9f0da205409d6ce
user.product:  60b25119c9f0da205409d6ce productId:  60b25119c9f0da205409d6ce
```

this is my code:

```js
setTimeout(async function(){
            const items = await req.user.cart.items;
            console.log(items);
            for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
                var user = items[i];
                console.log("user.product: ", user.productId, "productId: ", productId);
                if(user.productId == productId){
                    var result = items[i].quantity;
                }
            }
            
            const product = await Product.findById(productId);
            const productQuantity = product.productQuantity;
            const productQuantityResult = productQuantity + Number(result);
            product.productQuantity = productQuantityResult;
            await req.user.deleteCartItem(productId);
            await product.save();
        },  20000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your solution might not work in all cases, if the server crashed or was restarted, then you will lose the information about which product to get back to the stock and which to leave in the cart. I suppose you to use a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) that does this task for you.

You can track the time this product was added to the cart, and run a cron job every 5 minutes to check the products that exceeded 30 minutes in the cart, and then bring them back to the stock. There are many tools that can be used to create cron jobs, [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) and [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) are good options